# SEO impact of blog and website using the same domain, but on different servers

Tags: seo, subdomain, ip-address

I have recently launched my website, and a crucial part of it will be a sister blog.

Because of the complexities within the website, I felt it was better to host the blog on a separate server. This means they have separate SSL certificates, and IP addresses.

At the moment, the URL for both the web app, and blog, are as follows:

- https://mywebsite.com
- https://blog.mywebsite.com

Is there an SEO impact for having a blog/website on separate servers? If so, how can this be mitigated?

Many thanks.

Comment: *Is there an SEO impact for having a blog/website on separate servers?* Short answer? No.